# Save DataTable back to SQL Server using a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, stored-procedures, datatable

I have a WPF Datagrid that I am filling from a class in a middle tier of my application. The call looks like this

```
InvDataGrid.ItemsSource = CountGrid.getMonthEndNumbers("@S06", 23, 2, 2015).DefaultView;
```

The classes looks like this.

```
public class CountGrid
{
    public static DataTable getMonthEndNumbers(string StoreId, int iDay, int iMonth, int iYear)
    {
        return DataAccess.ExecuteDataTable("[dbo].[Inventory_CountGrid_Select]",
            DataAccess.Parameter("@StoreId", StoreId),
            DataAccess.Parameter("@iDay", iDay),
            DataAccess.Parameter("@iMonth", iMonth),
            DataAccess.Parameter("iYear", iYear));
    }
}
```

And this

```
public class DataAccess()
{
    private static string connectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.dbcon;

    public static DataTable ExecuteDataTable(string storedProcedureName)
    {
        return ExecuteDataTable(storedProcedureName, null);
    }

    public static DataTable ExecuteDataTable(string storedProcedureName, params SqlParameter[] arrParam)
    {
        DataTable dt = default(DataTable);
        using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            cnn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = cnn;
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = storedProcedureName;
                if (arrParam != null)
                {
                    Array.ForEach(arrParam, param => cmd.Parameters.Add(param));
                }
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                dt = new DataTable();

                try
                {
                    da.Fill(dt);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception(Convert.ToString(ex));
                }
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }

    public static SqlParameter Parameter(string parameterName, object parameterValue)
    {
        SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = parameterName,
            Value = parameterValue
        };
        return param;
    }
}
```

So now I am trying to save the changes that are made in the DataGrid back to the database but I am having trouble doing so. Prior to moving to WPF and splitting my solution into three projects I was able to do the same thing using code like this (cut some of it for brevity).

```
private void GetRecords()
{
    SqlDataAdapter da = default(SqlDataAdapter);

    da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT blah1, blah2 from Table", con);

    da.TableMappings.Add("Table", "MeInventory");
    ds = new DataSet();

    da.Fill(ds);
    ds.Tables["MeInventory"].DefaultView.AllowNew = false;
    dgvInventory.DataSource = ds.Tables["MeInventory"];

    da.Dispose();
    ds.Dispose();            
}

private void SaveRecords()
{
    if (ds.HasChanges())
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = null;
        SqlCommandBuilder cb = null;

        da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT blah1, blah2 from Table", con);

        da.TableMappings.Add("Table", "MeInventory");

        cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
        da.Update(ds);               

        cb.Dispose();
        da.Dispose();               
    }
}
```

I would have that in my code behind and just call the `Get` and `Save` with a button. However now that I have separated most of the code behind from my forms I am having trouble conceptualizing how I would accomplish the same thing. I had briefly thought about looping through the `DataTable` and saving one row at a time but I am thinking there has to be a better way. And while searching for a better way all the samples I found wrote the SQL inline (like what I did in my sample above) and I wasn't able extrapolate the differences from inline to a stored procedure.

So, with all that said, How do I save my changes in the DataGrid back to the database without looping through the table and doing one record at a time?

Comment: At this point my Data Binding skills are mostly Win Forms level so there is no MVVM, MVP, or any other WPFish pattern being used in this application.

Comment: have you thought about passing the data to a stored procedure as XML and creating a temp table(s) the via xml you can emulate a bulk Insert.. or you can check out how to create a custom type on the sql server to handle the datatable.. I personally prefer the XML Approach.. also it's not a bad idea to Insert the data using a loop until you become more proficient.. where is the Insert / update code btw..? also avoid explicit `Dispose()` method calls and wrap your objects around a `using(){}`